# When searching for implicit conversion, does Scala use the destination type?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scala-2.11

I'm reading the book *Scala in Depth*, chapter 5 about implicits. The author says this on page 102:

> The implicit scope used for implicit views is the same as for implicit parameters. But when the compiler is looking for type associations, it uses the type it's attempting to convert ***from*** [my emphasis], not the type it's attempting to convert to.

And yet, a few pages later he shows an example, with a `complexmath.ComplexNumber` class.  You import `i`, which is a `ComplexNumber`, and call it's `*` method, which takes a `ComplexNumber` argument.

```
import complexmath.i
i * 1.0
```

To convert 1.0 into a `ComplexNumber`, this finds an implicit conversion that was defined like so:

```
package object complexmath {
  implicit def realToComplex(r: Double) = new ComplexNumber(r, 0)
  val i = ComplexNumber(0, 1)
```

But that contradicts the first statement, no?  It needed to find `Double => ComplexNumber`. Why did it look in the `complexmath` package, which is part of the implicit scope for `ComplexNumber` but not for `Double`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either source or target works:

```
object Foo {
  implicit def bar(b: Bar): Foo = new Foo {}
  implicit def foo(f: Foo): Bar = new Bar {}
}
trait Foo
trait Bar

implicitly[Foo => Bar]  // ok
implicitly[Bar => Foo]  // ok

val b = new Bar {}
val bf: Foo = b  // ok
val f = new Foo {}
val fb: Bar = f  // ok
```

So I think that sentence is wrong (?)

Comment: At first I thought your b: Foo was repl output, mangled by cut/paste.

Comment: @som-snytt Ah ok, I edited it a bit so it is more clear

Answer (score 2):

The spec says about views:

the implicit scope is the one of T => pt.

i.e., `Function[T, pt]`, so implicit scope includes the classes associated with both `T` and `pt`, the source and target of the conversion.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class B
class A
object A { implicit def x(a: A): B = new B }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
defined class B
defined class A
defined object A

scala> val b: B = new A
b: B = B@63b41a65

scala> def f(b: B) = 3 ; def g = f(new A)
f: (b: B)Int
g: Int

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A
class B
object B { implicit def x(a: A): B = new B }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> val b: B = new A
b: B = B@6ba3b481
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding his text.

The compiler will look for the implicit conversion in all available scopes until it finds a suitable one.

In the example you specified it'll find one being provided by the **complexmath** package.

However, is the definition of 'suitable one' that we are interested here. In case of implicit conversions, the compiler will look for a conversion **from** **Double** to the expected type **ComplexNumber**.

In other words, it'll inspect all conversions **from** **Double** until it finds one that can convert a **Double** to the target type.

Josh, the author, is not saying that the compiler needs a conversion defined in an object associated with the **Double** object. The conversion can be defined everywhere.

In this particular case, the conversion is defined in the package object associated with the **ComplexNumber** object. And that's normal, is the ComplexNumber object that 'wants' to be compatible with **Double**.

And since the usage implies the import of **ComplexNumber** and therefore the import of package '**complexmath**', the conversion will be always in scope.

Comment: About your last paragraph: the book makes a point of not importing complexmath._, so the `realToComplex` conversion function is not available without a prefix. Does that change your answer? The compiler does not, obviously, search through any and all packages to find conversions.

Comment: Package object 'complexmath' is imported because 'complexmath.i' is imported. The conversion is defined in the package object as a implicit def, so it'll be available. That's how I understand it. 
@jsuereth can you confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

So this is more about what the compiler already *know*s about an expression.

You have in the example:

```
import complexmath.i
i * 1.0
```

The compiler looks at this to start with:

1) I have a type for `i`, it is `Complex`
2) I have a method on `i` called `*`, it takes an argument of type `Complex`
3) You passed me an `Int`, but I need a `Complex`.   let's see if i have an implicit which gives me that.

This example works because the `*` method is defined on Complex.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay, the crux is step 3. `realToComplex` is not available as an un-prefixed identifier, so in step 3, it searches in the "implicit scope" -- but, the implicit scope of what type(s)? The book seems to me to clearly state: `Double` (ie, the *from* type).  But reality seems to be: both `Double` and `ComplexNumber`.  The conversion is found in the implicit scope of `ComplexNumber`, because that implicit scope contains the package `complexmath`, which contains the conversion function.

Comment: It depends upon what the compiler knows.  At this point, the compiler knows that it has an `Int` and the `*` method requires a complex, so it looks for `Int => Conmplex`, which means it will look in both Int and Complex.

However if you had 1.0 * i, the known facts are different.

Comment: `1.0 * i` finds the same conversion and compiles, just like `i * 1.0`.  Maybe things have changed since the book.

Comment: Yeah, at least for that example it has.  I believe Scala may look at both types in the expression before looking up implicits now, where-as before it would only look at the left-hand-side *first*.   The right-hand-side lookup, i believe, happens after the left-and-side logic, but I fail to recollect the details.

Comment: Oh, also note: I wrote that section several years ago now.  Implicits, unfortunately, are intimitely tied to how the compiler is implemented.  As Scala improves its user experience and removes bugs, some aspects of concern may improve.   Hoping to get a 2nd edition out for 2.12, but we'll see.